# How to get Linux man pages in Windows XP

Tags: linux

I'm using Ubuntu 9 as a virtual machine in Windows XP , so it doesn't have updated man pages for Linux(my machine doesn't support newer versions) . I tried to Google for few man pages that i haven't found in my virtual machine .But, what if there is a network problem?So ,i want man pages for Linux to be available in Windows XP .I tried to get such "application" or "man pages in pdf/html format",but couldn't find any? Please someone give me a solution? I mostly needed man pages for system calls.

Comment: You can browse it online http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html

Comment: Of course but what if there is no internet connection when i needed them

Comment: A similar question has been asked at askubuntu
  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/155743/how-to-download-the-official-man-pages-from-the-manpages-ubuntu-com-for-offline

Comment: Did you consider installing a newer Ubuntu directly on your laptop

Comment: Why would you want the man pages of newer versions than what you have installed? You have the man pages for your actual software, that's what you need.

Comment: I'm learning operating system concepts ,so i wanted updated man pages to learn commands and system calls for Linux

Comment: see my hardware configuration doesn't support newer versions of ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the core man pages for Linux from [here](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/). This includes documentation for most POSIX-mandated APIs (including system calls) and for several Linux-specific issues, but *not* the man pages that come with various utilities.

You can then use a man page viewer for Windows, either via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), or using `groff` for Windows, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/944434/507519).

Alternatively. the `Makefile` in that distribution contains an `html` target, which uses `man2html` to generate HTML versions of the man pages.

Quite honestly, it might be simpler to build a more up-to-date VM - having documentation that pertains to newer versions than the software at hand can be quite frustrating...